# Display more than one variable of same type using Natvis

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code, natvis

I am trying to demonstrate here the approach which I have followed to display two `uint32_t *` type variable using `Natvis`.

- `sample.cpp`

```cpp
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    uint32_t foo_array[5] = {5,15,96,8,77};
    obj_1.pointer_array = foo_array;
    uint32_t * pointer_array_1 = foo_array;

    uint32_t limit_array[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        limit_array[i] = i*5;
    }
    uint32_t *limit_ptr = limit_array;

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried to display both `pointer_array_1` and `limit_ptr` by the following way, but unfortunately I can only see the value of `pointer_array_1` in the field of `limit_ptr`. Even if the `DisplayString` is also same.

- `test_file.natvis`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">
    <Type Name="uint32_t *">
        <DisplayString>Test IndexListItems</DisplayString>
        <Expand>
            <IndexListItems>
                <Size>5</Size>
                <ValueNode>pointer_array_1[$i]</ValueNode>
            </IndexListItems>
        </Expand>
    </Type>

    <Type Name="uint32_t *">
      <DisplayString>Would like to observe limited or preferred ranged value</DisplayString>
      <Expand>
        <IndexListItems>
          <Size>10</Size>
          <ValueNode>limit_ptr[$i]</ValueNode>
        </IndexListItems>
      </Expand>
    </Type>

</AutoVisualizer>
```

The output is shown in the following figure:

[image]

My desire to see in the window of `limit_ptr` the value `0,5,10,15,20,.....,45`

##### I have tried to use the following style of `natvis` but failed too.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">
    <Type Name="uint32_t *">
        <DisplayString>Test IndexListItems</DisplayString>
        <Expand>
            <IndexListItems>
              <Size>5</Size>
              <ValueNode>pointer_array_1[$i]</ValueNode>
            </IndexListItems>

            <IndexListItems>
              <Size>10</Size>
              <ValueNode>limit_ptr[$i]</ValueNode>
            </IndexListItems>
      </Expand>
    </Type>

</AutoVisualizer>
```

Right now, both values are glued to each other. I have got same output for both variables.

[image]

Is there any way, to display multiple variables of the same type using `Natvis`?

Comment: You should not use the variable name in the natvis. Can you try to change your code to `<ValueNode>this[$i]</ValueNode>`?. If that works (I only have VS, not VS code, and VS does not support natvis for typedefs, so I cannot test it), I'll make my comment an answer.

Comment: @WernerHenze If i don't use the `variable name` how the process will be done? Eg: I could have several `same` type variable of same/different size (lets say: `a,b,x`). In which line I will say debug value will be shown only for `x` and `a`?